# Car stalls in idle with AC on

Tags: ac, rpm

My cars RPM drops when I switch on the AC. So I need to keep pressing the acceleration pad when at rest. Its fine when I'm driving the car its alright but when I get stuck in some traffic I got to turn off the AC.

Its so hot in summer, if some one provide an useful solution it would be highly appreciated.

Its a Lancer evo VIII

Comment: What make and model do you have? What size engine, and are there any other problems even if they seem unrelated?

Comment: Without any information on the car, first thing i would check is your alternator or your battery, assuming its a petrol sounds like the AC is sucking too much power to let the engine continue to run properly.

Comment: Lancer evo VIII @2009

Comment: Does it high idle properly when the engine is cold?  thinking it could be an idle control valve not properly raising the idle while the AC is on.

Comment: Does the car ever stall if you come to a sudden stop? Could you get us the fuel trims?

Comment: Ya my dad told me about some incident like that

Answer (score 1):

You could have either [a clogged or stuck IAC valve](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/24047/7132).  Try opening the idle air screw a bit ( say one or one and a half turns ) and see if that helps.

If not, it could also be something like the bearings on the compressor seizing up.

Comment: The IAC is electronically controlled here. There's no screw to turn.

Comment: @Zaid there may be no screw to turn, but that has nothing to do with the IAC being electronically controlled. Both my current cars have electronically-controlled IAC valves and they still have idle air screws.

Answer (score 1):

clean throttle body most likely it is full of carbon, and removed the idle control valve clean with fuel system cleaner buy it at any parts store :)